# ¿Cómo enviar y leer un array desde laravel a Jasper studio?

Tags: laravel, jasper-reports, jasper

quisiera saber cómo puedo leer una variable (que es un array) enviada desde laravel en Jasper Report. Yo se recibirla como parámetro pero para leer cada uno de los valores que contenga dicho parámetro de manera individual no se como hacerlo.

Esta variable la tengo en Laravel:

```
    'decreto' => [
       'empresa' => 'Empresa de prueba',
       'titulo' => 'CERTIFICADO DE ESTUDIOS',
       'numero_decreto' => '17486',
       'descripcion_decreto' => 'De acuerdo Resolución Nacional No. 17486 del 17 de noviembre de 1984',
       'texto_firma_individual' => 'CERTIFICA',
       'texto_firma_grupal' => 'CERTIFICAN'
    ];
```

Necesito poder leer este arreglo en Jasper, enviándolo a un solo parámetro 
y no por parámetros individuales.

Agradezco cualquier sugerencia!

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow, para poder ayudarte necesitamos que compartas el código que tienes hecho hasta el momento! :)

Comment: Gracias @Capt.Teach he actualizado mi publicación, espero haber sido claro. quedo atento.